# Gauss Law - non-spherical surface

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

in a lot of textbooks (e.g. *Berkeley's Physics Course, II tom by Purcell*) there're derivations of the Gauss Law for non-spherical surfaces as presented below:

[image: schematic]

[image: equations]

The problem is - I cannot understand why there's a $\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}$ term.
Here's another picture, where my doubts are even more visible:

[image: schematic no 2]

When you project $dS$ area onto a plane where $dS_0$ area is, it'll not match with (cover) the $dS_0$ area (even after shifting - at least if my calc. was right), therefore you cannot use $\cos(\alpha) = \frac{dS_0}{dS}$ (or $dS = dS_0  \cdot\frac{1}{\cos(\alpha)}$).

Could you please explain me how does it work? Where did that $\frac{1}{\cos(\alpha)}$ term come from?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your objection

Comment: maybe I've got it a little bit overcomplicated. At the end what I've meant was: how to proof that cos(αlfa) = dS_0/ dS, because in case of a cone it doesn't seem to be trivial. Or at least I'm blind :)

Comment: Think of the triangle with $\text dS$ as the hypotenuse and $\text dS_0$ as the leg adjacent to angle $\alpha$

Comment: I'm trying, but since the slant height of a cone is not perpendicular to dS_0 it doesn't create a rectangular triangle together with dS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

> When you project $\text dS$ area onto a plane where $\text dS_0$ area is, it'll not match with (cover) the $\text dS_0$ area

Yes, it will, because that's by construction.  The $\text dS$ area is the projection of $\text dS_0$ onto the surface.

What they're really saying:

- Start with a cone that comes from the charge, with a radial $\mathbf E$ field. There's a constant flux down that cone.
- Have any (locally flat) surface cut across that cone to form a patch $\text dS$.
- Note that the flux through that cut surface ($\text dS$) has to be the same as the flux down the cone, regardless of the angle.

Comment: by construction...? Sorry, but I'm not satisfied with this answer :/ Whenever I try to imagine it - there's always something not right. E.g. here: https://imgur.com/a/HtTpWFY . dS doesn't clearly project onto dS_0, even after moving. 
I've also tried to parameterized the lines (by y=ax+b etc.) to find if you can construct there a rectangular triangle, but I've end up with implicit function...

Comment: @baciek It looks like you are misunderstanding what $\text dS$ is. Those red lines in your image should be intersecting on the cone.

Comment: @AaronStevens, well if they do - you still cannot create a rectangular triangle there. I've assumed this position of dS in order to have vectors dS and dS_0 starting in the same point.

Comment: @baciek I don't think you're going to get a perfect triangle. I'm sorry I was somewhat misleading with my comment on your question. I was just trying to give you a rough sense of the idea of the projection.

Comment: no rectangular triangle - no cos(a) = dS_0 / dS. Where's the key to solution then? Are we assuming that since dS is small enough, so we can neglect the inperfection of rect. triangle?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Since you’re constructing the cone (lots and lots of cones to cover the surface) you do it so that it’s a sufficiently good approximation. Although in physics we usually skip the formalities, math has a formal epsilon-delta method in calculus to prove that this converges to the exact answer.

Comment: alright, probably the least satisfactory solution I could imagine. Bacause when you look at https://imgur.com/dOUpYRN (this is how I imagine it, hopefully it's right) dS clearly doesn't project onto dS_0 "so easily"... Guess I'll need to believe in it. On the other hand when you think about cone so small and thin  that it edges are nearly parallel (and I believe this is how integral calculus works), the term cos(alfa) = dS / dS_0 will work.

Comment: well yeah, as I was writing my last comment I realized that "nearly parallel walls" of the infinitly thin cone are the key to the solution. Thank you for joining the journey through the void of my mind...